# CVNN and Tensorflow

Tags: python, neural-network

How the algorithm use Complex Value Neural Network ( all complex value, like: input, weight,bias and output) in python

Answer (score 0):

**Tensorflow** supports complex numbers as type: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/dtypes/complex

Here is a **work** showing how **complex numbers** could be used in **neural networks**: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.09792.pdf

Here is the **source code** of that work: https://github.com/ChihebTrabelsi/deep_complex_networks

In their code authors use Keras and Theano as backend - you just substitute (install) Tensorflow as a backend.